# How does one export the list of stored WMS-servers in QGis?

Tags: qgis, wms

Could anyone point me as to where QGis stores the list of WMS-servers you added?

I have built a fairly large list of WMS-server on one computer, but the QGis-project file which gets accessed by my collegues doesn't load ALL of the layers (to keep startup quick).

Occasionally though, a wms layer is required for which I have the needed url info saved, but they cannot acces it. Therefor, I'd like to make local duplicates of the WMS server list I have in my setup onto the other computers.

**So far the idea, the problem is I'm clueless as to where to find the stored list, and if I can just copy/paste that into the matching folder on another computer**

(Using QGis 2.0.1 still on most computers, fiddling around with 2.2 locally before I go and upgrade on all (~12) PC's.

Comment: Please do not put "SOLVED" in your Question title - the way to indicate that you have a solution is to either click the Accept button next to the most helpful Answer you received, or if none led you near it then write (and Accept) your own Answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To share the WMS connections list you can "Save" the XML file (from the form "add WMS/WMTS layer) and "Load" it in every client.

[image]

Comment: Right, how did I feel to see that? :o  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Don't worry, I also totally missed this just a few weeks ago... :)

Answer (score 5):

It isn't needed to edit the registry, at least for QGIS 3.x.
All your connection preferences are stored in `QGIS3.ini` located in

```
 C:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini
```

Look for the `[QGIS]` block right before `[Processing]` in `QGIS3.ini`. You can append already stored multiple connections from one user to the `[QGIS]` block of an other user.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Windows, you can export the WMS settings from the registry.

For Windows XP and Windows 7, they are stored under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS\QGIS2\Qgis\connections-wms
```

You can export the key as .reg file, which is human readable, and import it on other computers with the same OS.

Comment: Much to my surprise, the xml is fairly readable to humans aswell. While I am running the 'base computer' on XP, I prefer to avoid fooling around with the registry. That said, most of the other computers are on Windows 7. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: I don't see any differences between XP and Windows 7 for the registry entries.