# Update a WMS Connection list automatically

Tags: qgis, wms, xml

I'm working on QGIS 2.8

Is it possible to automatically update an XML document containing a list of WMS connection
and if that file can automatically follow my QGIS project file

For example, if I add a new WMS layer in my project, save my project and close it. I want the WMS XML file to be updated.

Comment: this thread may help.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93865/how-does-one-export-the-list-of-stored-wms-servers-in-qgis